# Excluding properties from auto mapping in Fluenet NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I would like to create a convention class that would ignore properties staring with certain
prefix like "ig_". I did try implementing IPropertyConvention interface and calling clear() on columnname property. But this didn't work. Any ideas?
Thanks
- Fahad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it across-the-board currently, you'll need to specify an [override](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/AutoMappingOverrides) or [ForTypesThatDeriveFrom](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/AutoMappingAlteringEntities) call for each entity.